# sql - table format for monthly wise

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, data-modeling

I have a data of 300 students monthly wise for an year please suggest me in which table format I have to store that data. I want to compare monthly wise data per each student.

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you mean by "table format"?

Comment: what you have tried so far, coz you can have separate table for each month or you could put all in a single table. So please add more details to your question.

Comment: @codeomnitrix - "separate table for each month" is almost always a really bad idea.  In the rare exceptions it's just a bad idea.

Comment: ok, i was not very much clear with the question so just thought of it. Anyways thanks :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need at least two tables.

One table, Students, holds the core details for the  student; these are the attributes which occur once for each student, no matter how many months are recorded (such as name).  Let's assume its primary key is STUDENT_ID.

The second table will hold the records for each month.  Its primary key would be (STUDENT_ID, MONTH_ID).  The MONTH_ID needs to identifier both month and year (as in most school systems an academic year spans calendrical years).

Depending on the precise details of your "data of 300 students monthly wise" you may need more tables.

Comment: The data in the student table is data that occurs once for each student, no matter how many months are recorded.